# JQuery's Ajax function works in chrome but returns 404 in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, cross-browser

I'm using a central ajax function to send ajax Post requests to a server. This is the code of the function:

```
function postJson(url, jsObj, whenSuccess, whenError){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                "Content-Type": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
            },
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),
            success: function(result){
                if(whenSuccess !== undefined){ whenSuccess(result); }
            },
            error: function(xhr){
                if(whenError !== undefined){ whenError(xhr.status); }
            }
        });
    }
```

When I try to run my application it works fine in chrome, but in firefox it throws a 404. My REST service helper returns a 404 when the accept or content type isn't set to JSON... so I thought that firefox might not add the headers but when I look at the sent request:

```
Request URL:
http://localhost:9081/api/1/localize/validation.json

Request Method:
POST

Status Code:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Request Headers
08:40:10.000

X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequestUser-Agent......
Referer:http://localhost:9081/kportal/
Pragma:no-cacheHost:localhost:9081
Content-Type:application/json, text/javascript; charset=UTF-8, */*; q=0.01
Content-Length:2
Connection:keep-alive
Cache-Control:no-cache
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

You can see that the necessary headers are set. Still I'm getting a 404 in firefox but not in chrome.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Remove `headers` then check.

Comment: If I remove the headers than it will fail in chrome as well?

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain AJAX request?

Comment: I am not making a Cross-Domain AJAX Request, but after taking a closer look at the Chrome headers, I found Origin:Localhost:.... there. The REST Service might not accept requests without this headers.. I'm figuring that out now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
function postJson(url, jsObj, whenSuccess, whenError){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        accepts: {
            xml: 'text/xml',
            text: 'text/plain'
        },
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsObj),
        success: function(result){
            if(whenSuccess !== undefined){ whenSuccess(result); }
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            if(whenError !== undefined){ whenError(xhr.status); }
        }
    });
}
```

Refer [What is the point of jQuery ajax accepts attrib? Does it actually do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065252/what-is-the-point-of-jquery-ajax-accepts-attrib-does-it-actually-do-anything)

Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks, but I need to perform a POST request. Not a get. The GET request is refused by the REST server by default.

Comment: Then you have to add additional `headers` in the `REST` file. Which language are you using?

Comment: I am not allowed to make any changes to the REST Service. It may only accept POST requests.. so making the service accept GET request isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks, that worked... I didn't think it would. Why is this working? I am not seeing any request header changes... ?