# I have issue with ajax call on one exam

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I bumped into this question on exam. Can someone help with it. In my research I found that dataType is something like 'json' or 'xml' not the exact mime-type.
Accepts in other hand use literal object to define mime-types.(judging by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065252/what-is-the-point-of-jquery-ajax-accepts-attrib-does-it-actually-do-anything#answer-11065286)). Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: {
        xml: 'text/xml',
        text: 'text/plain'
    }
});
```

And content type is for

> When sending data to the server, use this content type.

from jQuery documentation.

If someone can help with this question will be great. Thanks.

Exam Question:

> You are developing a web application that retrieves data from a web
>   service. The data being retrieved is a custom binary datatype named
>   bint.  The data can also be represented in XML. Two existing methods
>   named parseXml() and parseBint() are defined on the page.
>
> The application must:  ? Retrieve and parse data from the web service
>   by using binary format if possible  ? Retrieve and parse the data from
>   the web service by using XML when binary format is not possible
>
> You need to develop the application to meet the requirements.  What
>   should you do? (To answer, drag the appropriate code segment to the
>   correct location. Each code segment may be used once, more than once,
>   or not at all. You may need to drag the split bar between panes or
>   scroll to view content.)

Code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    uri: '/',
```

option 1: `accepts: 'application/bint, text/xml',`

option 2: `contentType: 'application/bint, text/xml'`

option 3: `dataType: 'application/bint, text/xml'`

```
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {
```

option 1: `if(request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type" == 'application/bint')`

option 2: `if(type == 'application/bint')`

option 3: `if(request.mimeType == 'application/bint')`

```
    },
    success: function(data) {
        start(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Judging by the jQuery documentation can't be dataType. "The available data types are text, html, xml, json, jsonp, and script."

Comment: My guess is that accepts(option 1) and getResponseHeader(option 1) is the correct answer, just a guess. This is the reason to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the key here is this bit:

> The data being retrieved is a custom binary datatype named bint.

This means that you're expecting `bint`, not sending `bint`. Therefore, the answer here is `accepts`.

For the second part:

1. `type` is not a MIME type, it's a string (source [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))
2. `request.mimeType` is not a valid property of `XmlHttpRequest` (source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties))

Therefore the answer is `request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") == 'application/bint'` (source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader()))

Comment: This is the correct answer to this question and a correct explanation as well.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1: `accepts: 'application/bint, text/xml'` because it's expected a bint or xml type

Option 2: `if(type == 'application/bint')`

it's like bellow

```
dataType: xpto,
dataFilter: function(data, type){
    alert(type); //xpto
}
```