# Ajax call SPRING MVC - url not found error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I make an ajax call to populate dynamically a select tag on user's option.

```
function updateSelect(){
    var ddlTool = $('#selectTool');
    var ddlAction = $('#selectAction');
        ddlTool.on('change',function(){ 
            //append the placeholder
            ddlAction.html('<option value="NONE">Select action</option>')
            var option = ddlTool.val();
            $.ajax({            
                url: "/eMuse/loadActions",
                    data : {id:option}, 
                success : function (response){
                    debugger;
                    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                        ddlAction.append('option value="' + response[i].value + '">'+
                                response[i].text + '</option>');
                    }
                }
            });
    });
}
```

In Controller i have this method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadActions", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<DropDownListItem> loadActionsGET(@RequestParam("id") long id) {

        // load actions by selected tool
        List<ActionViewModel> actions = StudentModelMapper
                .mapListActionDTOToListActionVM(actionService
                        .getActionsByIdTool(id));
        List<DropDownListItem> items = new ArrayList<DropDownListItem>();
        for (ActionViewModel a : actions) {
            items.add(new DropDownListItem(String.valueOf(a.getIdAction()), a
                    .getName()));
        }

        return items;

    }
```

If i run :

> `http://localhost:8080/eMuse/loadActions?id=1`
>   i also get the NOT FOUND error

In my web.xml file i have map the servlet like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If i replace the url-pattern `*.html` with `/*` then I am able to run the link above, but everything else falls apart.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the request mapping to be `/loadActions`

However you have told spring to only be responsible for urls with this pattern :

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

You probably want to change the url pattern, to `/*`, or change that specific request mapping to `/loadActions.html`

Comment: If I change the request mapping to /loadActions.html i get NOT ACCEPTABLE error. The link generated by jquery is `http://localhost:8080/eMuse/loadActions.html?id=1`

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean.

Comment: @laura http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065252/what-is-the-point-of-jquery-ajax-accepts-attrib-does-it-actually-do-anything

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. I don't understand why if I change the url pattern to `/*` I get error 404 on each page i run